# Date Search for Automatic Reporting - Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok I've been through this site forward and backward before asking this but for some reason I can't get the code I've implemented to work automatically. I just need the script to run (I setup a trigger already) to check the email in column 3 of sheet 5 (called Reports). I need it to send me an email with column 1 data and column 2 data if today's date matches the date given.

Can someone look at the code and give me a little help?

```
function sendEmails() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Unique ID for spreadsheet');           

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[4];

  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 250;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();   

  var emailAddress = 'email@email.com';
  var subject = "Report Today";

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    if( row[3] == true) {
      var message = row[0]+row[1];
      try {
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      } catch(errorDetails) {
        MailApp.sendEmail("Email@email.com", "sendEmail script error", errorDetails.message);
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You mentioned that you are verifying if there is a value for the email, but what's the input in that cell? If it is a string, then row[3] == true will always return false, thus not sending the email.

Comment: I thought I formatted that column to be a date. What should I do instead?

Comment: If that column is a date, make sure that you are correctly parsing the hours so that the dates match. I'll post my code as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the dates match to be able to compare them, by setting the time (hours, mins, secs) equal to 0.

```
function sendEmails() {

     var spreadsheet =     SpreadsheetApp.openById('[Spreadsheet_Id]');           

      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[4];

      var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
      var numRows = 10;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4);

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();   

  var emailAddress = 'email@email.com';
  var subject = "Report Today";

  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    row[3].setHours(0,0,0,0);
    if( row[3] == today ) { 
        Logger.log("Send email with: " + row);
        var message = row[0]+row[1];
        try {
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        } catch(errorDetails) {
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "sendEmail script error", errorDetails.message);
        }
      }
  }
}
```